# Security warning from extension_builder: action is publicly accessible

Tags: typo3

I created an extension with the extension builder.

On saving I get this message:

`The object was updated. Please be aware that this action is publicly accessible unless you implement an access check. See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/extension_builder/User/Index.html`

How can I fix this issue? Yes I read the page but there are no useful hints.

Comment: Do you know which action is meant by this message? Which object did you update? And can you post it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the question is how you can "fix the issue": There is no issue, it is a warning, you can remove it and make your request secure. (As in the other answer.)
The "hint" on the page is actually very straightforward. The "issue", that a user is able to manipulate the url and make the server to execute a not wanted action.

Here is an example:
You have a list of users of your page and you can open thier public porfile for more information:

```
https://yourdomain.com/list/?tx_ext_plugin['action']=show&tx_ext_plugin['userId']=41.
```

So if I want to make some trouble, I change the action "show" to "delete" and may I am able to delete the poor user "41" from the db. That is bad.

```
https://yourdomain.com/list/?tx_ext_plugin['action']=delete&tx_ext_plugin['userId']=41.
```

So since it is you business logic typo3 offers no out of the box solution for this. That is why this warning from extension builder says, that you need to make actions to prevent misuse.

Regarding how to implemnt a better security here are some thoughts about the Access Control and some ideas what to implement in your actions:

**1) FE**

- You can separate your actions into different plugins. So if you have a public list action it can not be modified to the plugin that responsible for the delete action. How is it possible? TYPO3 will look the page record in your database. And will render it, and if there is a plugin on the page with the signature "tx_ext_plugin" then it will get the sent parameters. In this case you have the possibility to add the different plugins to different pages so changing the signature of it for an attacker won't help, because:

  1. If the delete action is not registered by the plugin, TYPO3 will
     throw an exception.
  2. If you are trying to change the whole signature the page won't be able to identify the plugin.
- You can add the edit / delete plugin to pages where a user has to be logged in. You can even manage multiple usergroups. Like normal user can only edit its profile, but a premium user can make further changes. You can use in fluid a view helper [IfHasRole](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Security/IfHasRole.html) that can show parts of your template for defined user groups. (There is an [ifAuthenticated](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Security/IfAuthenticated.html) ViewHelper too)
- You can take the extension "femanager" as an example. There is a controller "EditController", that covers actions like "update" and "delete". For example before making the update action there is a check if the logged in user has the same user id as the record which going to be changed. If you have a complex example you can make a check on the user group also.

**2) BE**

It is actually almost the same as frontend.

- BUT instead of plugins / user groups assigned in page settings. You can use different mountpoints, so BE users can not see folders where they are not allow to edit / delete.
- You have those two ViewHelper for the BE too. There names are: [f:be:security.ifAuthenticated](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Be/Security/IfAuthenticated.html) and [f:be:security:ifHasRole](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Be/Security/IfHasRole.html). However ifAuthenticated is also for FE, in a BE context it does not make sense.
- You have also the possibility to identify the id and userGroups of the BE user and you can make your own checks before you let an action run.
- You have also the possibility to turn on / off a module for a certain BE group.

+1: It is nothing to do with any action but just to list it too. There is also the possibility to allow / disallow field for BE Users by editing a record through the List mode in the BE.

Answer (score 4):

Extension builder creates dummy actions to update and create records. Those example actions do not contain any security checks, whether the caller actually is allowed to do so.

So it is your job to add adequate access control to those methods. E.g. make sure the current user (be it Frontend or Backend) is actually allowed to update the model in question.

Comment: can you maybe give an example? or can I just check in each controller method if user is admin?

Comment: Actually this answer is correct, however I wrote an extended answer. Because this adds almost nothing to the meaning of that hint. And it was mentioned that even that hint is not clear... It would be nice to implement some example and some description about how TYPO3 works and handles security regarding this topic.